# Teradata Database: Is a unique, composite key possible?

Tags: composite-key, teradata, composite-primary-key

This is my first time truly working with composite keys.  I have a record that consists of three foreign key columns.  The combination of these three keys must be unique.  If a duplicate record is inserted, a constrain error should be thrown just as if it were a unique, single-field, primary key.

This is for Teradata database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce this via a unique secondary index on the table.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX {optional name} ({column1}, {column2}, ... column{64}) ON {database}.{table};
```

You could also consider adding a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the table  as well if the inclusion of the `INDEX` would not benefit as an alternative access method.

Teradata also supports the use of Primary Key *constraints* if you are planning to enforce RI in your environment.

Comment: Decided to go a different route.  Marking this as answer since I will probably never get around to testing it, so anyone else feel free to comment if you don't feel this answer is acceptable.